# Image doesnt load on Xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have trouble with image loading (just on this pc, on other one its ok)

Im tried a few ways to put image

```
 <Image 
        MinWidth="190"
        Stretch="Fill"
        MinHeight="190"    
        Source="{Binding ImagePath, Converter={StaticResource UriToImageConverter}}">
        <!--If you use my way in answer you need replace Source like this-->
        Source="{Binding Image}"><!--Bitmapimage property in model-->
 </Image>
```

Its works only if I put path like 'ms-appx' but in target I need use  'Binding' its works on other pc witout any troubles but here I have "transparent" picture on a page

Comment: See [File access permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions).

Comment: User pick Image and I put 'StorageFile.Path' to 'ImagePath'

Comment: You should read the image file and use `BitmpaImage` as the source of the image.

Comment: @tao I have convertor wich return BitMap    `return new BitmapImage(new Uri(stringUri, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));`

Comment: @SmiLe you shoud use [SetSourceAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.setsourceasync.aspx) method.

Comment: Clemens has already answered in the very first comment - you can't access file in UWP by using direct path. If you want to show file outside your app's scope, use file/folder pickers and store permissions in future access list.

Comment: @Romasz wath please on the last comented code. Its work on other pc, how there I can got files and on this pc no?

Comment: @SmiLe maybe on the other PC the image is available in the local folder, but on your PC it's in another folder which is not accessable for UWP? if so, you can access the StorageFile itself by creating a copy of the image in a temporary folder which is in your local folder, then get the imagepath of the copy.

Comment: @Zure no, there I can peek any picture from disk in any folder what I want

Comment: @SmiLe Well no, in UWP you can't access any folder you want to. Did you read Clemens' link?

Comment: @Zure yes ive read it and I know it, but really its works on the other pc and there I picked pictures from network hdd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I just put images to `StorageFile`'s and copied it to local folder and take it from there and put into my `Model`'s property

Before:

```
 this.collageimages = await OpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
 for (var i = 0; i < this.collageimages.Count; i++)
{
  var stream = await collageimages[i].OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
  this.image = new BitmapImage();
  await this.image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
```

After:

```
this.collageimages = await OpenPicker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
 for (var i = 0; i < this.collageimages.Count; i++)
{
  await this.collageimages[i].CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "collageImage_"+i+"", NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
  var tempStorage = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/collageImage_"+i+""));
  var stream = await tempStorage.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
  this.image = new BitmapImage();
  await this.image.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
```

I do not claim to be the best answer if you know a better way, please write it

Comment: Also you can use [Tokens](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders)